# Stuck with this SQL error : "Must declare the scalar variable @XYZ"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on this query for a while and cannot figure it out the problem. All i am trying to do is get information from a table (largest order, who made that order) , stored it and print it out result as a message on the console. Thank you for all your help.

Here is my query:

```
USE DB;

DECLARE @BigCustomer table(CustomerName varchar(50), Itemtotal smallmoney);

    INSERT @BigCustomer 
        SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName), 
               MAX((ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) * Quantity)
    FROM Orders as o join customers as c 
            on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
         join OrderItems as oi 
              on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
    WHERE o.CustomerID = 3
    GROUP BY (FirstName + ' ' + LastName), 
             ((ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) * Quantity)

DECLARE @CN nvarchar(50);
SET @CN = (SELECT CustomerName FROM @BigCustomer)
DECLARE @IT smallmoney;
SET @IT = (SELECT ItemTotal FROM @BigCustomer)
DECLARE @PrintMessage nvarchar(50);
SET @PrintMessage = N'The largest order of ' + 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @IT) + N'was made by ' + @CN;

GO
PRINT @PrintMessage
```

Comment: Try to use `LIMIT` in your `SET @CN = (SELECT CustomerName FROM @BigCustomer)` for example and other `SET` command as well.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  As written, your `group by` statement doesn't make much sense.  Chances are you don't need any of those variables...

Comment: `@IT` is probably NULL. you never set it. Though you do set `@CN` twice. `SET @CN = (SELECT ItemTotal FROM @BigCustomer)` --> `SET @IT = (SELECT ItemTotal FROM @BigCustomer)` ? Can `CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @IT)` work with nulls?

Comment: this... does not look like mysql to me

Comment: This is tagged MySQL but the syntax looks suspiciously like SQL Server.

Comment: @sgeddes Thank you for your comment, yes i accidentally set `@CN` two times. Good eye! After correction, still getting the same error. `@IT` is SET to `ItemTotal` from `@BigCustomer` which is not NULL.

Comment: Try editing your question and supply sample data and desired results.  Your `max` aggregate looks to be negated by your `group by` clause.  Also, as others have said, please re-tag this as `SQL Server`.

Comment: @Brad Thank you, I corrected my typing error. `@IT` set to get value from `ItemTotal` from `@BigCustomer` which `is not NULL`.

Comment: @Edper LIMIT is a MySql extension to the language. It's not part of the sql standard and won't work on sql server.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: It was tagged as mySQL earlier see Gordon Linoff's remark.

Answer (score 0):

YUPPIE! I figure it all out. I `DECLARE`d two variables and assign the parameters separately instead of using one variable.

If i run the query i get this message:

> The largest order of $342.30 was made by Dave Hunter.

Here is the query:

I think i finally figured it out.

DECLARE @LOrder table(OrdTot money, OrdID int);

INSERT @LOrder

SELECT SUM((OI.ItemPrice - OI.DiscountAmount)*OI.Quantity), OI.OrderID
FROM OrderItems AS OI
GROUP BY OrderID

DECLARE @CName varchar(100);
DECLARE @OAmount money;

SET @CName = (SELECT TOP 1
        C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName
        FROM Customers C JOIN Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID JOIN @LOrder lo on lo.OrdID = O.OrderID
        ORDER BY lo.OrdTot DESC);

SET @OAmount = (SELECT TOP 1
        OrdTot
        FROM @LOrder
        Order BY OrdTot DESC);

PRINT 'The largest order of $' + convert(varchar(50),@OAmount) + ' was made by ' + @CName

Comment: How on earth is this reusable, when the CustomerID is hardcoded and doesn't appear to have any connection to the query pulling the largest order amount?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the query you have posted as an answer, you seem confused. Try building the resulting script by doing one thing at a time. First of all, do not use variables at the beginning, instead return the data using a normal query.

And as a basic query, use one that gets just the largest order and its ID. For that it would be enough to take only the `OrderItems` table, group the data by `OrderID` and limit the results to the topmost order total:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  OrderID,
  OrderTotal = SUM((ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) * Quantity)
FROM
  dbo.OrderItems
GROUP BY
  OrderID
ORDER BY
  OrderTotal DESC
;
```

In order to find out the ID of the customer who made the order returned by the above query, you can add a join to `Orders`. You will also need to modify the GROUP BY clause to include `CustomerID` into it:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  o.CustomerID,
  oi.OrderID,
  OrderTotal = SUM((oi.ItemPrice - oi.DiscountAmount) * oi.Quantity)
FROM
  dbo.OrderItems AS oi
  INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY
  oi.OrderID,
  o.CustomerID
ORDER BY
  OrderTotal DESC
;
```

At this point you could store `CustomerID` into a variable temporarily and use it in a second query to read the customer's name from `Customers`. That is not really necessary, as you can return all data in a single query:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  CustomerName = c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName,
  OrderTotal   = SUM((oi.ItemPrice - oi.DiscountAmount) * oi.Quantity)
FROM
  dbo.OrderItems AS oi
  INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY
  oi.OrderID,
  o.CustomerID,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName
ORDER BY
  OrderTotal DESC
;
```

As you can see, another join is added to the query and the GROUP BY clause is modified once again, to include the columns `FirstName` and `LastName`.

And now would be the time to introduce variable assignment to the query so that instead of returning the results as a row you could actually store and then print them.

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  @Customer     = c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName,
  @LargestOrder = SUM((oi.ItemPrice - oi.DiscountAmount) * oi.Quantity)
FROM
  dbo.OrderItems AS oi
  INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY
  oi.OrderID,
  o.CustomerID,
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName
ORDER BY
  OrderTotal DESC
;
```

Note that the query does not use a WHERE filter. You cannot possibly know the ID of the customer beforehand. It is the `TOP (1)` + `ORDER BY` technique that allows you to find it out.